# What is the purpose of xargs -I command?

Tags: shell-script, xargs

Can you explain what this command does:

```
files=(this_is_filename)
for filename in ${files[@]}; do 
  ls -t1 ../htory/$filename* |
    head -1 |
    xargs -I fname cp -p fname ../htory2/somefile.CSV
done
```

Especially this part of this command

```
xargs -I fname cp -p fname ../htory2/somefile.CSV
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`xargs` transforms input to arguments. The `-I` option specifies the string to be used as a placeholder for the argument. Therefore, if the pipeline outputs something like

```
file1
file2
```

then the `xargs` line transforms that to

```
cp -p file1 ../htory2/somefile.CSV
cp -p file2 ../htory2/somefile.CSV
```

The `head -1` only returns one line, though, so I can see no real benefit of using `xargs` instead of, say

```
cp -p "$(ls -t1 ../htory/$filename* | head -1)" ../htory2/somefile.CSV
```

Moreover, since the target file is always the same, it will be overwriten by the last file in `${files[@]}`.

Comment: @Stephane Chazelas: Well, since there are no double quotes at the `for` line (`for filename in "${files[@]}"`)...